# Spring AOP, pointcut expressions : annotation with specific param

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I have `Aspect` class with method `clear()`.

```
@Aspect  
public class Clear 
{
   @After("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")  
   public void clear()  
   {  
      // do smth  
   }
}
```

now I want call this aspect after each execution of method with annotation `@Transactional` with `readOnly = true` like

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)  
public void someMethod()  
{ 
   //... 
}
```

is there way to do it without custom annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are quite close.

In your `clear` method, you should take in a parameter of type `JoinPoint`.  This parameter will be auto populated by Spring at runtime, and with it, you can get details of your specific joinpoint, including the `java.lang.reflect.Method`, which will contain the annotation you are after.

I am thinking something like this:

```
@Aspect  
public class Clear 
{
   @After("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")  
   public void clear(final JoinPoint joinPoint)  
   {  
      final Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
      final Transactional txAnnotation = methood.getAnnotation(Transactional.class);
      final boolean isReadOnly = txAnnotation.readOnly();

      //do conditional work based on isReadOnly
   }
}
```

Comment: So simple solution. Thx!